# A way to do 3D flip in HTML/JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

We have an image that needs to spin on the page - it's not a square image (well..the image is square, but it's an irregular shape on a transparent background).  Getting it to spin isn't a problem, but when it goes on its side it completely disappears - we need it to be a "3D" image so it doesn't disappear as it moves around?

Answer (score 1):

http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/

The described solution uses the native CSS transitions. If these are not supported by the browser, it falls back to the jQuery Flip plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The thickness part is probably where you won't get any results with CSS/JavaScript (yet). How would the browser know how your object looks from the side?

Faking this for rectangular objects is easy, just put some divs around the sides and make a very thin box.

For irregular shapes you could try using the same image cloned a few times behind your original and offset by half a pixel on the z-axis. This might still look weird from the side.

See this [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/NAHxy/) where I created the effect I was talking about. The problem with this approach that, although you have can provide thickness through layering, there is no way to tell the browser that this is actually a solid medium.
You can get away with this effect if no animation is involved though.